# On a certain limit.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\omega$ be an arbitrary irrational number and $ \alpha>0$. Show that  the following equality 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to
\infty}\frac{\sum_{(i_1,i_2,\cdots, i_n) \in \{1,\cdots,n\}^n}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\{i_k\omega\}^{\alpha}}{2^k}}{n^n}=\frac{1}{1+\alpha}
\end{align*}
holds true, where $\{.\}$ denotes the fractional part of the real number (i.e.,$\{a\}=a-\lfloor a \rfloor)$)

Comment: It seems like a much simpler thing which has been spitefully obfuscated.

Comment: For a specific $k$, the $i_j$ with $j\neq k$ just provide a factor of $n^{n-1}$, which almost cancels the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

The sum consists of $n^{n+1}$ summands, very many of which repeat. For given $j, \ell \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$, how many $(i_1, \ldots, i_n) \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}^n, k \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ are there such that $k = \ell$ and $i_k = j$? We know $k$ must be $\ell$ and $i_k$ must be $j$, but $i_j$ for $j \neq k$ can be arbitrary. So there are $n^{n-1}$ such summands.

This allows us to simplify the sum:

$$\begin{align*} 
\sum_{(i_1, \ldots, i_n) \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}^n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ \{ i_k \omega \}^{\alpha} }{2^k} & = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n n^{n-1} \cdot \frac{ \{ j \omega \}^{\alpha} }{ 2^{\ell} } = n^{n-1} \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n \{ j \omega \}^{\alpha} \cdot \sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac{1}{2^{\ell}} \\[1ex]
& = \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \right] \cdot n^{n-1} \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n \{ j \omega \}^{\alpha}.
\end{align*} $$

Therefore:

$$\frac{ \displaystyle \sum_{(i_1, \ldots, i_n) \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}^n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ \{ i_k \omega \}^{\alpha} }{2^k} }{n^n} = \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \right] \cdot \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \{ j \omega \}^{\alpha}.$$

The first factor can be omitted since it tends to $1$. Now the interesting part: since the sequence $\big( \{ j \omega \} \big)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is [equdistributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) on $[0, 1]$ (because $\omega$ is irrational), by the Riemann integral criterion for $f(x) = x^{\alpha}$, the following equality holds:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \{ j \omega \}^{\alpha} = \int \limits_0^1 x^{\alpha} \, \mathrm{d} x.$$

It remains to compute the integral:

$$\int \limits_0^1 x^{\alpha} \, \mathrm{d} x = \left[ \frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{1+\alpha} \right]_{x=0}^1 = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not full proof but I believe you can piece it together from two concepts.

Idea 1: For any given $\omega$ the truncation function you gave gives a random number generator for the uniform density on $[0, 1]$.

Idea 2: Your sum for large n looks like a uniform distribution over the set of all $n$ tuples of numbers from $1$ to $n$.  So you could rewrite it conceptually as:
$$E[\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{X_k^\alpha}{2^k}]$$
Where $X_k$ are uniform independent random variables on $[0, 1]$.

So we want to evaluate:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty E\left[\frac{X_k^\alpha}{2^k}\right]$$
The moment generating function for the uniform distribution is $M[t] = \frac{e^{t}}{t}$.  This gives moments for all integers $\alpha$ to be equal to $\frac{1}{1 + \alpha}$.
Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{1 + \alpha}}{2^k} = \frac{1}{1 + \alpha}$$

You could probably use the [Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory) to prove it. The stationary measure of the ergodic mapping being uniform density on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Both answers are very nice and correct.